# Google Analytics Ecommerce Suddenly Stopped Tracking and I don't know why

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce

I'm asking if anyone is having the same problem as I currently am and if they can help. Currently, for the past 5 days or so, The Google Analytics E-commerce section has not been recoding any payments or revenue when in the back end we know it is happening.

This started when the client added Facebook pixel to the website but was reassured that their IT team did not touch any of the tracking codes for the rest of the website.

Below is the graph of when E-commerce stopped tracking.

[image]

I have double-checked the entire flow and double-check the tracking codes to the entire website. But this still hasn't shown what the problem could be.

Any help would be appreciated and has this ever happened to any of you guys as well? This has only happened once about 2 years ago (same client) when E-Commcerce tracking just stopped without a reason and came back about a month after.

Answer (score 0):

Is the tracking hardcoded on the site or are you using Tag Manager?

My guess is the pixel broke some code, I don't know if the GA hardcoded or the dataLayer.

Do a test transaction, on the confirmation page do the following: Right Click on the site > Inspect > Console

Check if you get error, could you paste them here?

Also if you're using GTM, can you type 'dataLayer' on the confirmation page. It should return something.

This is just to understand the problem. I need more info to give you a solution.

Comment: The website tracking code is hardcoded to the site. I've done a test transaction and it went through and got confirmation and everything but it still did not fire to GA (generated no errors as far as console is concerned).

Comment: If i gave you the website address for you to try and see if anything is broken would that help? Bare in mind that the website is old and the code is slightly messy.